# Ng-switch in ng-repeat issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an odd issue that is driving me crazy

I basically have a list of article of different type: news, tweets and video

I am rendering them like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:-timestamp track by item.id" ng-switch="item.type">

        <?php  
             include("templates/ang-youtube.html");  
             include("templates/ang-tweet.html");
             include("templates/ang-news.html");
        ?>

</div>
```

Inside each include i am doing something like this:

```
<div class="item" masonry-brick ng-switch-when="news">
...content in here
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="item" masonry-brick ng-switch-when="tweet">
...content in here
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="item" masonry-brick ng-switch-when="youtube">
...content in here
</div>
```

Now the problem is the youtube items are always rendered first. The order of the items (timestamp) is ignored. The tweets and news items though render correctly.

If i remove the switch and just list out the items as text then everything is in the correct order. As soon as I add the switch the youtube items are rendered first again.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I have tried moving the switch inside the ng-repeater like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:-timestamp track by item.id">

    <div ng-switch="item.type">
            <?php  
                 include("templates/ang-youtube.html");  
                 include("templates/ang-tweet.html");
                 include("templates/ang-news.html");
            ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

But it makes no difference. The youtube items are always rendered first.

If i inspect the $scope.items array they are ordered correctly by timestamp.

I have also tried using an ng-if instead of a switch but get the same outcome

Any ideas? :-(

Also tried using ng-include like this:

```
<div ng-include="'templates/ang-{{item.type}}.html'"></div>
```

But that doesn't work

Comment: All those php includes don't really make sense when you could just use `ng-include` with a dynamic url based on type or create your own custom directive for this. Get used to the server only being a data source and put your templating and business logic into angular

Comment: I have tried using ng-include makes no difference. Same outcome. Youtube items are rendered first.

Comment: A better explanation of expected results would help along with a data sample. See [mcve]

Comment: I am expecting to see items ordered by date with newest first. The news items and tweets work correctly. But the youtube items are already rendered first. Even though their date is older. I have checked scope and order is correct. No matter what i do youtube items are rendered first. Will try and get some example data together.

Comment: A demo that reproduces the order problem in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) or other sandbox site would also help

Comment: It may be related to masonry re-ordering things also, hard to know without a demo

Comment: Aaaah - i revisited the angular-masonry documentation and there is a "preserve-order" attribute which seems to fix the issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

DOH!!! Needed to add the preserve order attribute as outlined here

https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry